# How to get data from Firebase in recyleview Adapter in android

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

**Good Morning All**

**I want to get Get Data from Firebase in Recycleview Adapter**

This is My Firebase Structure :

[image]

In My recycleView Adapter , Data comes from api.

**Explanation of firebase Structure**

Here **user_product_bid** is my main node ,under that **"42"** is my product_id (sub Node)and  under that "bids" value available. I want to get data from firebase as per adapter positionwise product_id.I have Successfully post data from recycleView but problem occurs in fetching

Please Help me how i can complete this task or suggest me .

Comment: use retrofit to call data

Comment: try this tutorial https://inducesmile.com/android/a-simple-android-todo-list-app-with-recyclerview-and-firebase-real-time-database/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to fetch the data and populate it into recyclerview

```
List<User_Product_Bid> userPdtBidObj = new ArrayList<User_Product_Bid>();
private DatabaseReference firebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
private DatabaseReference 
        userPdtsBidRef = firebaseInstance.child("user_product_bid");
userPdtsBidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            long count = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            if(count != 0) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataObj : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                  User_Product_Bid obj = dataObj.getValue(User_Product_Bid.class);
                  userPdtBidObj.add(obj);
             }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        });
```

Model Class for User_Product_Bid

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class User_Product_Bid {

    @SerializedName("bids")
    private boolean List<String> bids;

    public User_Product_Bid() {
    }

    public List<String> getBids() {
        return bids;
    }

    public void setBids(List<String> bids) {
        this.bids = bids;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this .. there is an easy way. but u have to make a Model class for that. it's up to u ...

```
databaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String product_id = data.getKey(); //your product id
            Arrylist<String> bits = data.getValue(); //bits for this product

                    }
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```